# Identify a 70's road frameset

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage

I'm at a loss on the manufacturer of this frameset, any ideas are appreciated.

Its previous owner claims it is 50+ years old and was bought in Chicago 46 years ago.

Bike has Nervar Star crankset, Pivo bar and stem, and Simplex gear change. Also a French saddle. Frameset as shown with Campagnolo drops, wrap around stays, long point lugs, and flat crown.

[image: one]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

Comment: Pretty generic.  The chromed dropouts are a bit distinctive (a minor step up from my old Nishiki), but there's nothing that really identifies it, if no one recognizes the stamping on the dropout.  (Can you make out the words behind the stamped number?)

Comment: @DanielRHicks The text looks like Brev. Campagnolo. Pretty standard stuff for patents.

Answer (score 3):

My first clue was from the serial number which started with a J. The French derailleur also pointed me to this direction: I took a guess and searched for [pictures of Jeunet frames](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=lLRYXLWHKITj_Aalj4iwBw&q=jeunet%20bikes&oq=jeunet%20bikes&gs_l=img.3...234697.235040..235168...0.0..0.96.419.5......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i19j0i8i30i19.obJRl4s4oZM).

Then, browsing a bit I saw [this forum](https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/1012918-show-me-your-jeunet.html) which shows many pictures of similar models where the lugs are exactly the same, similar dropouts and forks chromed. My guess; it is a **Jeunet 620** or a very similar model.

[image]

**Edit**:

Well, I looked a bit more and found this [catalogue](http://www.velovintageagogo.com/t947-catalogue-jeunet-annees-70-dole-jura). If you look at the *course* (racing) section, their top of the line model for that year is called 570-10 (10-speed 570). The marking on the dropout might be just that, the model number. Identifying the year, now, that's something else.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking this might be a version of the 570. I'll pull the fork and hope to find a clue. I'll also verify the stem diameter.

Comment: The frame uses French threading in the bb shell and on the steer tube. The stem is 22.2mm.